# Angular2. RouteModule. Непонятная причина ошибки Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route

Tags: angular2

Добрый день. Изучаю Angular2. Встретился с непонятной странностью.
Пример из учебника:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from './hero-detail.component';
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
import {BackendService} from './backend.service';
import {Logger} from './logger.service';
import {HeroesComponent} from './heroes.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'heroes',
   component: HeroesComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
     AppComponent,
     HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot([
       appRoutes
    ])
  ],
  providers: [HeroService, BackendService, Logger],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

Имеем ошибку:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Invalid configuration of route '': Array cannot be specified ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Invalid configuration of route '': Array cannot be specified
Стек-трейс:
validateNode@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65001:15 [angular]
....

Практически тоже самое (без секции импорта модулей, для краткости)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [HeroService, BackendService, Logger],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Т.е. из const перенесли прямо в тело

Все работает замечательно! Я не понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте (где константа) у вас путь уже в массиве, поэтому дальше получается массив в массиве. Соответственно во втором варианте просто массив. Уберите один из массивов (квадратные скобки) в объявлении константы, например.